# I do not know why doFirst () and doLst () are not executed

Tags: gradle, task

I am using gradle 4.9.

DoFirst () and doLast () are not executed using Copy type.

```
task myCopyExtension(type : Copy){
    from 'original'
    into 'target'

    File newFile = file('original/newFile.txt')
    doFirst {
        println 'write to file'
        newFile.write('copy file', 'UTF-8')
    }
    doLast {
        File copied = file('original/newFile_copied.txt')
        if(newFile.renameTo(copied)){
            println 'copy complete'
        }else {
            println 'copy failed'
        }
    }
}
```

gralde myCopyExtension

noting pring

append -----

```
task myCopy(type : Copy) {
    doLast{
        println 'myCopy!!'
    }
}
```

gradle myCopy

Nothing is output.

T_T

Comment: Use `--console=plain` and you'll probably understand why nothing is logged.

Comment: gradle --console=plain myCopyExtension
> Task :myCopyExtension NO-SOURCE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 0s

Comment: So you get your answer: NO-SOURCE means that there is nothing to copy, and the task is thus not executed. The task should not create its own inputs. If you want to create a  file and then copy it, then write a task that creates a file, and make the copy task depend on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before your task executes gradle will do an up to date check to see if the task inputs/outputs have changed since last time it ran. So if 'original' and 'target' folders haven't changed since last execution gradle will skip the task

Also, you shouldn't mutate files which are used as task inputs as it will ruin up to date checking.

See https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:up_to_date_checks

Comment: task myCopy(type : Copy) {
 doLast{
  println 'myCopy!!'
 }
}

gradle myCopy
Nothing is output.